# Reverse DNS lookup to match hostname in authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, dns, sshd

I have several sysadmin laptops and a cluster of servers. I am administering / rotating ssh keys on the servers from a script (call it `rotate_keys.sh`) that will run on any of the sysadmin laptops.

I have established the rule that each server will retain at most 1 (the latest) ssh key of a given sysadmin laptop.

The ssh keys are stored in the file `authorized_keys` that takes the form:

```
key1 user@device1-hostname
key2 user@device2-hostname
key3 user@device3-hostname
```

Each server has a script (call it `update_keys.sh`) that upon execution via ssh, will remove all keys associated with the machine that is currently connected to it. I (attempt to) do this by removing all lines that contain the hostname of a given client.

```
sed -i "/$client_hostname/d" authorized_keys
```

On the server, I grab the hostname of the client by doing a reverse dns lookup on the ip address from the environment variable `$SSH_CONNECTION` (which is set at the beginning of the ssh session).

```
client_ip=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}')
client_hostname=$(nslookup $client_ip \
                | tail -2 \
                | head -1 \
                | awk '{print $4}')
```

This returns a hostname in the format:

```
device-hostname.router-hostname.
```

For a lack of a better term, it gives me a "fully qualified hostname".

However, the hostnames in the `authorized_keys` omits the hostname of the router (subnet) that these devices are connected to. They simply appear as:

```
device-hostname
```

So, when I perform the following delete command, nothing matches.

```
sed -i "/$client_hostname/d" authorized_keys
```

**Is there a way to either force the ssh daemon to record "fully qualified" hostnames. Or is there a tool for dns lookup that will only give me the name of the device, minus the hostnames of the routers its connected to?**

I'd rather one of the above two approaches than disabling reverse dns in the ssh daemon (on the servers) because that would require that my sysadmin laptops have static ips.

Comment: Can you not just cut the end off the device-hostname when you do the nslookup? Or have i misunderstood? `cut -d . -f1` after your `awk` will do that.

Comment: @DeclanGallagher I can cut it off. I am hesitant to do that because I know that in the `authorized_keys` the full name isn't there only because I am on the same network. But, once i take the sysadmin machines off the same network as the clusters, i'd get fully qualified namessuch as hostname.example.com. So I wan't ssh daemon to always used fully qualified if possible to `authorized_keys`

Comment: The thing after the key is technically a comment field of unspecified payload, it just has the user in there by convention. I think I'm too confused about who puts what where to know whether that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following awk command:

```
nslookup $client_ip | awk '/name =/ { split($4,add,".") } END { print add[1]}'
```

This will run the nslookup command, look for all lines with names = and then split the 4th space delimited space field with . putting the results in the array add. We then print the first element of the array to reveal the hostname for the last entry found.